# How to make an ajax call for creating post in same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an create.js and new.js files in controller. I am getting an error in create function

This is my create action in post controller

```
def create
  @post = @topic.posts.new(post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
  respond_to do |format |
    if @post.save
      format.js { render action: "create" }
    else
      format.js { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb:

```
<%if @post.errors.any? %> 
  alert("<%= j @post.errors.full_messages.join('; ') %>"); 
<% else %> 
  $('#new-post form').remove(); 
  $("#new-skill-link").show(); 
  $(".post-list ul").append('<%= j render(@post) %>'); 
  alert("Post Successfully Created"); 
<% end %>
```

My error is `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: Please, add important details to the question itself via "Edit" button, not to comments

Comment: Could you please full error message and corresponding part of server log. How do you call `create` action? Is it just "Save" button in the form? If yes, maybe you forgot to add `remote: true` to the form?